# Does the ×4 cost of armoring a mount apply to base cost or total cost?

Tags: dnd-3.5e, equipment

I'm looking to armor a mount. As per the chart on page 123 of the Player's Handbook, this mount is a Large Nonhumanoid, meaning the barding will cost four time as much and weight twice as much for the respective armor for a medium humanoid.

The only issue I have is the DM can't make up his mind on whether or not the factor of four increase applies to only the armor's base cost, or also applies to the masterwork and material cost of the armor.

Does any one know how exactly this is calculated, perhaps through the deconstruction of some 3.5 magical mount armor by price? ×

Answer (score 7, accepted):

On page 217 of the DMG, it states that “the cost of the masterwork quality and any magical enhancement remains the same” regardless of a creature’s unusual size or shape.

Answer (score -1):

Ambiguous by RAW.

I've always read it as determining the base price of the armor, with MW, enchantment, and any other modification being applied as normal atop the new base price. Analysis of established pricing of magic items and adventure module loot listing and such does provide some scattered support for this approach, and analysis of game balance supports it quite strongly (applying the multiplier to the costs of enchantments, especially, quickly gets out of hand and essentially amounts to a soft ban on enchanted barding), but ultimately, there is no RAW answer, because the rules accounting at all for the existence of tool-users other than Small and Medium humanoids is an afterthought, and they simply didn't bother to consider such details.