# What is the cost of magic armor for large creatures?

Tags: dnd-3.5e, magic-items, armor, creature-size, pricing

armor does not resize and mundane armor cost 2x if bought for a creature of large size.

Does this multiplayer apply to the cost of magical armor as well?

Say a suit of armor cost 50 go (full plate) masterwork would be 150 total. Large creature makes it 300 (150×2) or 200 (50×2+100)

That armor is made with a +1 enhancement. Which cost 2000 gp, for a large creature would it cost 4000 gp?

Whenever a player buys a magic weapon or armor from the magic item compendium, do they pay 2x?

Comment: Seems similar to this: https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/62146/does-the-×4-cost-of-armoring-a-mount-apply-to-base-cost-or-total-cost

Answer (score 6):

The *Dungeon Master's Guide* offers the following:

> Armor for Unusual Creatures: The cost of armor for nonhumanoid creatures, as well as for creatures who are neither Small nor Medium, varies from the values given on Tables 7–3 and 7–4, as described in the Armor for Unusual Creatures sidebar on page 123 of the Player’s Handbook. **The cost of the masterwork quality and any magical enhancement remains the same.** (DMG p.217)

Thus, *only* the cost entry in the table for armor is affected by that rule; that is - only the mundane, non-masterwork price of the armor is affected.

---

For the example of +1 full plate armor made for a large creature, the cost would be **4,150 GP**. 3,000 GP from doubling the cost of medium full plate armor, 1,000 GP from the +1 enhancement, and 150 GP from the masterwork armor component. [Do note that armor enhancement costs and weapon enhancement costs are *not* the same. Your question seems to assume that a +1 armor enhancement costs 2,000 GP, which it does not.]