# Can you craft or buy enchanted barding?

Tags: dnd-3.5e, magic-items, armor

In reviewing the rules for barding, I came across the below statement:

> Barding can be made of any of the armor types found on Table: Armor and Shields.

Now this is interesting because of magic enhancements to armor. Could you conceivably craft and/or buy for instance *+2 full plate barding of ghost touch*?

Comment: What about this strikes you as odd?

Comment: not odd per say, just an interesting place to explore if magic enchantments can be used on barding.

Comment: Related, as it assumes that magical barding is possible: [Does the ×4 cost of armoring a mount apply to base cost or total cost?](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/62146/does-the-×4-cost-of-armoring-a-mount-apply-to-base-cost-or-total-cost)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

### Yes, you can acquire magical barding

Barding is armour, and nothing in the rules prevents you from enchanting that armour just as you would any other similar item. [The rules for magical armour](http://www.d20srd.org/srd/magicItems/magicArmor.htm#armorforUnusualCreatures) specifically note that:

> **Armor for Unusual Creatures**
>
> The cost of armor for nonhumanoid creatures, as well as for creatures who are neither Small nor Medium, varies. The cost of the masterwork quality and any magical enhancement remains the same.

Which makes it clear that it is not just ordinary humanoid armour for small/medium creatures that can be enchanted, and doing so costs no more than enchanting "normal" armour (even if the base price of the armour is higher). Barding is the only other kind of armour described in the rules.

Such equipment is especially important to druids and rangers specifically; getting magical equipment for their animal companions is necessary to keep them relevant as their master gains levels, and the game (and community) generally assumes that these characters are investing appropriately in equipment for their companions.